# SSJS functions - Platform.Function.GUID() and Platform.Function.UpsertData - no records in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, upsert

Trying to use ssjs 2 functions - Platform.Function.GUID() and Platform.Function.UpsertData in the Script Activity
Added Script Activity into the Automation and executed Run Once. No errors, however no data in the fields 'CustomerVehicleId' and 'InternalID' in the DE 'customerVehicle' (DE is in Parent BU)
My code:

```javascript
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");
    try {
        var DE_NAME = "customerVehicle";
        var COLUMN_NAME = "CustomerVehicleId";
        var CustomerVehicleId = Platform.Function.GUID();
        var rows = Platform.Function.UpsertData(DE_NAME, ["InternalID"], [["1"]], [COLUMN_NAME], [CustomerVehicleId]);
        // Log the result of UpsertData
        Write(Stringify(rows));
    } catch (e) {
        // Log any errors
        Write("An error occurred: " + Stringify(e));
    }
</script>
```

Any ideas why it doesn't fill in the data?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra set of square brackets around the third UpsertData parameter.

```javascript
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");
    try {
        var DE_NAME = "customerVehicle";
        var COLUMN_NAME = "CustomerVehicleId";
        var CustomerVehicleId = Platform.Function.GUID();
        var rows = Platform.Function.UpsertData(DE_NAME, ["InternalID"], ["1"], [COLUMN_NAME], [CustomerVehicleId]);
        // Log the result of UpsertData
        Write(Stringify(rows));
    } catch (e) {
        // Log any errors
        Write("An error occurred: " + Stringify(e));
    }
</script>
```

**Results**

[image: results]

I would also verify the location of the DE -- if in shared and the script is in a child BU, then you need the `ent.` prefix on the DE Name.  Field lengths and data types could also be in play.  I would test it in a CloudPage to see the output and for debugging.